# Server crashing on HTTP.call with Meteor + mismatched async results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting two very weird results trying to make some basic GET calls with Meteor's HTTP library.

These same requests work fine with Curl and python, so it's not on the side of the API.

**1. Result not consistent with with result from async callback**

I'm using the below code in my meteor methods:

```
//snip! Meteor methods continued above. 

  getEmails: function(authId, threadId){
  result = HTTP.get("https://api.nylas.com/threads", {auth:authId}, function(error, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
  return result
}
```

Using chrome developer tools I'm able to examine the returned object.

```
Object {statusCode: 401, content: "{↵  "message": "Could not verify access credential.",↵  "type": "invalid_request_error"↵}", headers: Object, data: Object}content: "{↵  "message": "Could not verify access credential.",↵  "type": "invalid_request_error"↵}"data: Objectheaders: ObjectstatusCode: 401__proto__: Object
```

Now here's the weird part: Notice that I also have a console.log in the async callback. That output on the server actually returns the data I would expect to receive from a correct API call!

It's a bit lengthy and personal to post, but it returns a status 200.

**2. Using params in the call crashes my server**

This is a copy of the code above with a very slight change (including params options).

```
//snip! Meteor methods continued above. 

  getEmails: function(authId, threadId){
  result = HTTP.get("https://api.nylas.com/threads", {params:{id:threadId}}, {auth:authId}, function(error, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
  return result
}
```

Making this change completely crashes the Meteor server anytime I call this method.

This is what's printed to the chrome developer tools:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'getEmails' Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.(…) Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.
```

And here's what I'm seeing on the server:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
W20151110-20:52:42.024(-8)? (STDERR)     at    packages/http/httpcall_server.js:74:1

W20151110-20:52:42.024(-8)? (STDERR)     at packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1

W20151110-20:52:42.025(-8)? (STDERR)     at Request._callback (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:116:1)
W20151110-20:52:42.025(-8)? (STDERR)     at Request.self.callback  (/Users/max/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.murctg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:344:22)
W20151110-20:52:42.025(-8)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
W20151110-20:52:42.025(-8)? (STDERR)     at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/max/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.murctg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1239:14)
W20151110-20:52:42.026(-8)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20151110-20:52:42.026(-8)? (STDERR)     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/max/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.1.murctg++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1187:12)
W20151110-20:52:42.027(-8)? (STDERR)     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20151110-20:52:42.027(-8)? (STDERR)     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

This all seems very basic, so I'm surprised it's not working.

What am I missing that's causing all of these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusing sync and async (particularly with `HTTP`) is a really common mistake with meteor. Here's the rule: If you want to get the result back out of the method, use a synchronous call. See [this section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) of the docs for an example. Your implementation should look something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getEmails: function (authId, threadId) {
    check(authId, String);
    check(threadId, String);

    try {
      // note that options is a single object
      var options = {auth: authId, params: {id:threadId};
      var result = HTTP.get("https://api.nylas.com/threads", options);
      // this is just a guess - you should log the result to find
      // out what parts you need to extract
      return result.data;
    } catch (e) {
      // something bad happened
      return false;
    }
}});
```

On the client you'll do something like this:

```
Meteor.call('getEmails', authId, threadId, function(err, result) {
  return console.log(result);
});
```

---

Note:

1. `options` must be a single argument. You were passing two values for options, but the `HTTP.get` methods assumes it's 3rd argument is a callback. In your case it was an object, and thus the errors.
2. According to the [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) auth doesn't belong in params -- so that's what's causing the 401 error in your Basic HTTP Authentication.
3. This implementation only works on the server, so place it under your `server` directory or wrap it in an [isServer](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_isserver) block.

Comment: Hey David -- that's a helpful generalization. I switched to a synchronous call and my implementation is basically identical to yours, but I'm still getting the errors recorded in #2.

If you scroll over it seems to be asking me to add in the async callback.

What else can I try?

Comment: The only reason it would ask for a callback is if [HTTP.get](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get) is still running on the client. Trying to latency compensate a HTTP call is probably not a good idea (the meteor method could return before the HTTP request does) either use it on the client, outside of the method or in a server-only method.

Comment: @MaxCaldwell That error is expected if the method is defined on the client. As I point out in the "note" section of my answer, the method needs to be defined on the server. The easiest way to accomplish this is to put it in a file under the `server` directory in your app. See posts like [this one](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation) on latency compensation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your API request is receiving a 401 unauthorized challenge response.

You may need to proxy your request to avoid the challenge.