# Need clarification on calling Meteor methods asynchronously

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, meteor

So i've been doing some reading and I think I have a general grasp on this subject but could use some insight from someone more experienced. I've been trying to write a simple RSS reader in Meteor and have been facing some issues with calling the Meteor method asynchronously. I currently define the method on the server(synchronously) and call it on the client(asynchronously). What I don't understand is that when I try to make the HTTP.call on the server, I return an undefined value passed to my client if I pass a callback into the request. But when I make the API request synchronously everything seems to work fine. Is this the normal behavior I should expect/the way I should be making the API call?

```js
Meteor.methods({
  getSubReddit(subreddit) {
   this.unblock();
   const url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '/.rss';
   const response = HTTP.get(url, {}, (err, res) => {
    if(!err) {
     //console.log(res.content);
     return res;
    } else {
     return err;
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

Here's the method defined on the server side. Note that logging res.content shows that I'm actually getting the right content back from the call. I've tried reading some other answers on the topic and seen some things about using Future/wrapAsync, but I'm not sure I get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644547).

Comment: Thanks @DavidWeldon. So if I understand correctly, if I want my call on the server to run asynchronously, I would have to store the return value of the call somewhere on the server and then pass that to the client?

Comment: Typically the pattern is: (1) client makes an async call to a server method, (2) the method makes a sync call to some service (using try/catch like my example) and then returns the value to the client, (3) the client receives the data and does something with it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP.get` is doing async work, so callback passed to it will be called out of this meteor method call context.

To get desired result you should do it like this:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  getSubReddit(subreddit) {
    // IMPORTANT: unblock methods call queue
    this.unblock();
    const url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '/.rss';
    const httpGetSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.get);
    try {
      const response = httpGetSync(url, {});
      //console.log(response.content);
      return response.content;
    } catch (err) {
      // pass error to client
      throw new Meteor.Error(...);
    }
  }
});
```